# How to handle a topic where a biology answer is neeed following a claim by an official entity?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

A [question of mine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113540/has-the-ema-stated-that-there-is-no-herd-immunity-for-covid) was closed because off-topic. While I understand the rationale for pointing me to Skeptics SE, I probably failed to express my question correctly, thus this post.

The core of my question was: *does a COVID vaccine help herd immunity?* ← is this not a Biology question?

The context for this question was an answer from an EU official entity that effectively stated that it is not. ← this is the context, I am not trying to understand if the statement is a fake (it is not), something good for Skeptics SE.

My question here: would transforming the question into *does a COVID vaccine help herd immunity?* make it on-topic?

My fear is that without giving the context the answer will be "what makes you think it is not?". And with the context we are back to off-topic.

**EDIT**: I tried to completely reorgainze my question at [Does herd immunity applies to COVID?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/does-herd-immunity-applies-to-covid) and will delete the original one. I hope that it makes it a biology question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the question as it is now, it is a question which is better for skeptics.se. Especially when you take into account who asked the question and the likely intent behind it. The answer has been cut and used by vaccine deniers to basically say: "The EMA says the vaccine is not effective", ignoring it is only part of the answer.

Asking "does a COVID vaccine help herd immunity" will be on-topic (at least I would say so), but without going into the literature I am not sure if there is an answer which can give you a reason. It can also be on-topic in medical sciences.

Comment: *without going into the literature I am not sure if there is an answer which can give you a reason* → my assumption was that in the case of COVID specifically, there must have been quite a lot of research on that area (both biological, but also statistical). It was a key element in the vaccine effort.